# How to get player SteamID from Valve server queries?

Tags: steam

These queries: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Can return many things about a [TF2] server, such as player names, points, current map etc.

I see how to return a list of player names, but that isn't useful (players can freely change their names).

How can I return a list of SteamIDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A2S* queries can't do this. Instead, you'd need to use the [RCON Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol) and issue the `status` command.

The [A2S_INFO](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2S_INFO) query can return the *server's* steamID by passing `0x10` to the `Extra Data Flag (EDF)`, but this is the only SteamID you can get using the A2S* commands

Answer (score 3):

The **only** way to get list of SteamID's is connect with real source client and issue "status" console command.

There is a cfg-based solutions that dynamically generates special cfg files (that will be loaded by a game) with commands to sequentially connect to multiple server and issue "status" command. SteamID's will be written in console logfile (and can be easily parsed).

These programs called "server scanners" or "steamid scanners" and mostly used for scamming and statistic purposes, and can be found at official forums (facepunch.com is down at this moment)
https://www.google.com/?q=site:facepunch.com%20server%7Csteamid%20scanner